# Macbook Pro 2008 Gigabit Ethernet has become 100Mbps with Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, network, ethernet

I just noticed that the Ethernet port on my old Macbook Pro 5,1 (Late 2008, the first Unibody model) that is supposed to be Gigabit is limited to 100Mbps after I installed Mavericks. Does anyone know how to fix it?
It's just a basic install of Mavericks, no strange configurations, I'm using it as a home server.

Comment: Where are you getting your connection speed indication from? If it's from **System Report>Network>Ethernet>Media Subtype** it's telling you the actual connection speed rather than the Ethernet adapter's maximum available speed. Is your network actually running slower than it did before 10.9? Also, are all the other components on your network capable of gigabit speeds?

Comment: I ran a speed test using iperf between my Macbook Pro 2014 and this one and it never went over 94Mbps. 

Into Network prefs>Ethernet>Advanced>Hardware it states that the available speed is 100baseTX while it should be 1000baseT by hardware specs.

Comment: Has your network speed dropped noticeably since installing 10.9? And, just to cover all bases, is your modem/router/switch fully gigabit compliant, as well as your cables being cat5e (fully wired on all 8 pins)?

Answer (score 1):

Try another cable, or another port on the other end of the ethernet cable if available.